# SEO - be first and Get my own company section in google for my company name

Tags: seo

I want my company name to be first in Google when I search for it, since it is a unique name.   I also want it to have its own "section" with sub-links of the "about page" "product page" "contact us" page like any other big companies have.

For example, if I type any other big company, I get their website on the top row, but it also has sub-links of the "contact us" , "about us" and more...

[image]

When I search my company name in Google, I get two full search pages with my company name but all of them are from other sites that took my details from somewhere. **None of these links are my site pages!**

I already read articles about "keyword significance" and "crawl errors" and most of the webmaster tools, but did I miss something else?
How do I gather my site pages under my site link in Google?
Is there a configuration for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How old is your website?**

If you launched your website within the last year, it is probably a matter of being patient.  These these happen, but Google needs to trust your website first.

The links under your own listing are called "sitelinks".  There is no configuration for sitelinks.  Google has an algorithm that controls whether or not they appear.  That algorithm is based on how many people click on your listing once it is in the top position, and how well trusted your website is.  These things take time.

**Do all of these other sites with your company name also say what your website is?**

The best way to get reputation and trust with Google is to get references.  It sounds like you have a local business with a physical presence and website.  Each site that on which your business is listed should have your 1) business name, 2) Address, 3) Phone number, 4) Website.   If these listings don't have this information, contact them to update the listing.

**Is your website crawlable?**

To be listed on Google, Googlebot needs to be able to look at your pages.  If you haven't done so, log into [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/), add your website, and verify it.  Then you can see how much of your website is indexed and can test to see if Googlebot can crawl it.

**Does your website have your business name as the title?**

If you don't make the title of the site say what your business name is, then Google will not think that it is actually about your business.   You should also have your phone number and address on each page.

Comment: Thank you so much! i'm also working on Meta tag "Keywords" property which i read is less important but still is. for example:  <META NAME='keywords' CONTENT= ....   and it is written that i'm not alowed to repeat words but i don't undertand how, am i not allwed to repeat between each word or inside the words themselves. in short, am i allowed: "crm Israel","crm free","customer relationship management free","crm sales","crm hebrew".... should i do it like this or like that: "customer relationship management","crm","sales","hebrew" because i'm not allowed to repeat words or full phrases?

Comment: meta keywords are not used by Google in any way.  I don't put them on my sites anymore.